# How to clear Animation Listeners set by NineOldAndroids?

Tags: android, android-animation, nineoldandroids

I am trying to have a view animated in my app and am using NineOldAndroid for animations.
The desired effect is to fade the view out and then set it's visibility to gone so that it doesn't get clicked while invisible. Here is How I do it.

```
ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(view).alpha(0).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
```

The problem here is that the listener above sticks with the `view` and when I try to fade it in again the listener gets called again resulting the view to be `GONE` upon appearing.

```
ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(enterGallery).alpha(1);
```

How can I clear the listener after the view visibility is set to `GONE` in the first piece of code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution and it would be to pass null as listener when making the view `VISIBLE`.

```
ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(view).alpha(1).setListener(null);
```